How do I set up router HDD to use microsecond timestamps?
I'm not sure if this is the correct forum for this question, but here goes.
I have an HDD connected directly to my router. It's supposed to accept backups of all the computers on the network. The backups use xcopy with the /d parameter, which is supposed to only copy files if they're newer. It is continually copying every file. I think I figured out why based on this page: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/running-xcopy-d-results-copying-non-updated-files-created-rational-clearcase
I confirmed that the timestamps of the source files have microseconds, and the destination does not.
At the bottom of the page, the solution is "Set up target file system to support microseconds timestamps."
I can't find anything online about how to do that. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Timestamp granularity depends on the file systems used. Check out robocopy /fft.
